# x-access-token not added to POST request

Tags: express, http, axios, jwt

I am using Axios calls from Redux actions to handle user authentication/authorization as I request or create resources. I have successfully done all of the creating/storing/signing of the tokens. When a user makes a GET request for resources, the header is passed along like this :

```
        return axios.get('applicants/', { headers: authHeader() }).then(result => {
        const applicants = []
        result.data.forEach(item => {
            applicants.push(item)
        })
```

And it works fine. The header contains the 'x-access-token' as it should. What doesn't work is when I make a POST like this:

```
        return axios.post('applicants/create', { headers: authHeader() })
        .then(result => {
            dispatch(_addApplicants(result.data))
        })
```

The 'x-access-token' isn't included in the header. The same function provides both routes with the token, so I'm sure it has something to do with different HTTP verbs. Anybody have any ideas?

Header on GET :

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'x-access-token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmNGJkMTRhMzcwOGNiNTViMDhmOGM1ZCIsImlhdCI6MTU5ODgwOTI0OCwiZXhwIjoxNTk4ODk1NjQ4fQ.7k4xi3kPo-aKyOf_5GNVv3pjO_WsIZwg8Ja1MgwfJCg',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36',
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w"'
}
```

Header on POST:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '204',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass your headers as the second argument to `axios.post`, but actually it should be third argument. Second argument is `data`.

```
    axios.post(
        "/applicants/create",
        {}, // add empty object or null here as second argument
        {
          headers: authHeader()
        }
      })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Works perfectly now.